# Create a underscore some function of my own for practice

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to a replication of the underscore some function.  I have been able to replicate every easy enough, but I'm lacking the understanding of how to isolate the boolean properly.  Here is what I have so far, thanks for the help in advance.

```
var some = function(collection, iterator){
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
        if(iterator(collection[i])){
            return false;
        }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'isolate' the boolean property.

The underscore function some should return true if any of the collection members pass the truth test, and it should not continue looping after finding the first true item.

So basically, I think you've got your return statements reversed:

```js
var some = function(collection, iterator){
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)
        if(iterator(collection[i])){
            return true;
        }
    return false;
};

console.log(some([1,2,4], function(thing){ return thing >=2; }));

console.log(some([1,2,4], function(thing){ return thing === 5; }));
```

Comment: Thanks I'm confused I wrote every using the format above.  Are they the same code then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you for your help.